# Count specific letters in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a question how to get number of characters from a string ?
In this scenario we got string: 'pppeerskka' and the outcome should look like '3p2e1r1s2k1a'

and the outcome should look like '3p2e1r1s2k1a'

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split the input string into rows, apply `count` function to it (so that you'd know how many different letters you have), and - finally - aggregate them back using `listagg`.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'pppeerskka' from dual),
  3  temp as
  4    (select substr(col, level, 1) letter,
  5            count(*) cnt,
  6            max(level) lvl
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= length(col)
  9     group by substr(col, level, 1)
 10    )
 11  select listagg(cnt || letter, '') within group (order by lvl) result
 12  from temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3p2e1r1s2k1a

SQL>
```

---

Converting it into a function is a simple task:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_count (par_string in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(30);
  5  begin
  6    with temp as
  7        (select substr(par_string, level, 1) letter,
  8                count(*) cnt,
  9                max(level) lvl
 10         from test
 11         connect by level <= length(par_string)
 12         group by substr(par_string, level, 1)
 13        )
 14      select listagg(cnt || letter, '') within group (order by lvl)
 15      into retval
 16      from temp;
 17
 18    return retval;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_count('pppeerskka') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3p2e1r1s2k1a

SQL>
```

Comment: It is working! Now I need to apply this in pl/sql function

Comment: That's easy; see edited answer.